# How to run .gif file in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Is it possible to run .gif file in cocos2d for iphone

Answer (score 2):

CCSpriteSheet works really well for animating with spritesheets, you'll need a way to generate the spritesheet from the animated gif.

[Read this.](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.4/interface_c_c_sprite_sheet.html)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean an animated GIF.  If so, no, not directly, but you could extract the frames and run them using any of the usual animation classes.